# Return resolved promise to another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

What I'm trying to do is to read a file from a path with `readline` and return transformed content back to another file which I couldnt solve with other similar topics on SO. If I `console.log` `logObject` in the module right before `return` statement I get exactly what I want - readable object, but in another file I get `Promise { <pending> }`. Here's the module I'm creating:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

// Parse temperature log file into JSON object

const parseTemperature = async filePath => {
    let logObject = new Object;
    const file = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: file,
    })
   
    let iterator = 0;
    
    for await(const line of rl) {
        // get date of measurement
        let date = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(','));
        // get temperature in celcius
        let temperature = line.substring(line.indexOf('=')+1,line.length-2);
        logObject[iterator] = [date,temperature];
        iterator++;
    }  
    console.log(logObject);
    return logObject;  
}

module.exports = parseTemperature;
```

Here's how I try to import it in another file (last 2 lines):

```
const { parse } = require('path');
const path = require('path');
const parseTemperature = require('./src/helpers/parseTemperature');

const os = process.platform;

const scriptsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'scripts');
const logsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'logs');
const temperatureLogsPath = path.join(logsPath, 'temperature.log');

const temperatureValues = parseTemperature(temperatureLogsPath);
console.log(temperatureValues)
```

What should I change to get readable output in the file where I'm importing module? Or is there another way to read the file without using async await?

Comment: You must call `.then` on Promises to consume them and get their resolve value